# How to discharge go channel without using received data?

Tags: go

I created a channel and want to discharge it without using received values.
However, compiler doesn't allow me to write code like this:

```
for i := range ch {
// code
}
```

complains that i is unused

substituting _ for i doesn't work either

What is the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `_ = i` in your loop body? [Example.](https://play.golang.org/p/MYP1mC5xHb)

Comment: @abhink, yes - second line of text after the snippet

Comment: @abhink, seems ugly, I thought there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/oLBfEqSBxV):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    close(ch)
    for range ch {
        fmt.Println("for")
    }
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

output:

```
done
```

Comment: This works only if you close the channel. If you have in opened (or close later in another place) - then you get deadlock https://play.golang.org/p/yE_hzKfXep

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky: Yes,  try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/4teARWVQz7) channel not closed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `select` instead of `range`:

```
for {
        select {
        // read and discard
        case <-ch:
        // to avoid deadlock
        default:
            continue
        }

    }
```

But then again, are you sure you really need the channel if you're not reading from it?

Comment: I need channel, but was sort of commenting it out while writing code.

Comment: This works only if you close the channel. If you have in opened (or close later in another place) - then you get deadlock https://play.golang.org/p/yE_hzKfXep

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky, you're absolutely right. I realised at some point after posting the "rough idea" what I missed and absolutely forgot to edit the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stuck in infinite loop read values until channel is not empty:

```
exitLoop:
for {
    select {
    case <-ch:
    default:
        break exitLoop
    }
}
```

Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/UsIqdoAGZi

If you need "updatable channel" - which keeps only 1 last value, you may use this recipe - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107654/5165332